# Minimize the maximum distance between any adjacent stations

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

> 100 stations are given . Distance between the adjacent stations are not equal. You are     given 10 flags which you have to place amongst these stations. 1st flag is on the 1st station and the last flag is on the last station. Now put the remaining flags such that the total adjacent distance between the the two flags is minimum.

My approach is this:

Consider this question for 10 stations and 4 flags
Let the distance between them be as
**1-----2--3---4----5-----6------7-------8-9---10**

Where – represents the distance in units
It means distance between 1st and 2nd station is 5,
And hence the distance between the first and tenth station will be (5+2+3+4+5+6+7+1+3)
= 36

We apply binary search between 1st and 10th station hence we get 36/2 = 18

Hence we will choose the pivot as 18 unit of distance and apply binary search from

> (i)    1st and 18th unit of distance for 1st flag
>
> (ii)   19th and 36th unit of distance for 2nd flag

Average of distance is 9 for 1st flag which is more closer to 4th station
we place flag on station 4.

Average of distance is 9 and hence distance from starting is 27 which is more closer to 7th station
Hence we place 2nd flag on station 7.

Hence answer will be
**1**-----2--3---**4**----5-----6------**7**-------8-9---**10**
Hence maximum distance is optimized as b/w any two stations is  15 in this case
Similarly we can solve for 100 stations

Please check whether this approach is correct or there can be any more efficient.
Correct me if i am wrong
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those stations placed on a straight line?

Comment: @XiZhang Yes the stations are placed on the straight line

Comment: Can you elaborate the question furthermore? Is the total distance the sum of distance of pairwise flags? e.g. suppose we have 3 flags, is TotalDistance = Distance(flag1, flag2) + Distance(flag1, flag3) + Distance(flag3, flag2) ?

Comment: No it is the sum of the distances between 1st and 10th station

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here... but if the position of the 1st and the 10th station are fixed, wouldn't the distance between them be a constant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11838/discussion-between-xi-zhang-and-luv)

Comment: Problem description: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=10680926. So the topic title is correct, and the formulation of the problem is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong.  In your example move station 6 to position 24.  Your algorithm would still give 1-4-7-10 as the answer for a maximum distance of 15, but in fact 1-5-6-10 would be even better with a maximum distance of 14.

The polynomial time solution at http://www.careercup.com/question?id=10680926 (which you copied this question, poorly, from) has the virtue of being correct, but is far from the fastest answer.  Here is a faster answer for this problem.

Suppose that we start with the maximum distance we're willing to use.  We can start from the first station, use a binary search to find the farthest station we're willing to jump to, then search to find the farthest from that, etc.  Using this strategy we can write a function that takes the maximum input distance and tells us how many flags we used.  (If it can't be done, we can just report a very large number of flags - such as the number of stations.)

We can turn this into a function, input the biggest jump we're willing to take, it tells us how many flags we will need.

Now we can do a binary search for the smallest maximum distance that gives us the number of flags we want.

(You can speed this up by modifying that function to return the number of flags, and the smallest and largest input values that will give the same exact answer.  The extra two bits of information can be used to speed up the binary search.  This gives the fastest solution that I know of for this problem.)

Comment: what will be this maximum distance?
Please if you can elaborate more your approach for this question

Comment: @Luv Your problem is fundamentally the same as http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=180276 (it looks different, but it is the same, you're trying to break an ordered list into a specified number of chunks with the largest chunk as small as possible).  The solution that I am describing is at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=181499.  (All examples are in Perl, feel free to recode in your language of choice.)